# bash grep strings with specific length in a variable

Tags: bash, grep

I am having trouble grepping words of specific length.
I am trying to filter a list, here is my code:

```
WORD=$1
LENGTH=${#WORD}
FILE=${2:-/dev/stdin}
LIST=$(grep -e '^.{${LENGTH}}$' $FILE)
echo "$LIST"
```

This prints nothing, however the code works when I type 3 dots or something for character of length 3. How can I use my LENGTH variable in this code to get the words with the length that is specified in my LENGTH variable?

Comment: Single quotes prevent variable interpolation.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: but it doesn't work with double quotes either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
grep -e "^.\{$LENGTH\}$"
```

or

```
awk "length == $LENGTH"
```

or

```
grep -E -e "^.{$LENGTH}$"
```

Comment: what does -E do?

Comment: `-E` uses extended regular expressions, so that you don't need to escape the curly braces to make them special characters.